# multiple procedure call in a trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I would like to call multiple procedures from a trigger in postgres.

```
CREATE TRIGGER fn_trigger_notify_ev
AFTER INSERT
ON public.event_notifications
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.notify_events();
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.notify_events_count();
```

I have been getting error messages after executing this command so please let me know, is it possible to call multiple procedures in a trigger?

Error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "public"
LINE 6:   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.notify_events_count();
                        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "public"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 167
```

Is there any method to call multiple procedures?

Comment: You need to create two triggers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As commented, creating a trigger per procedure is one way. I think you could also just wrap the function calls to one procedure, like (**psql** example):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_notifies(
) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM notify_events();
    PERFORM notify_events_count();
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and in your trigger just:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.do_notifies();
```

Comment: Nice suggestion!  'Had to reformat the function call a little, but this seemed to work: PERFORM 'notify_events';

Comment: I had to change `void` to `trigger`, otherwise this works well.